# Elastic Search 6 Nested Query Aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

i am new to elastic search Query and aggregation.
I have a nested  document with the  following mapping

```
PUT /company
{
 "mappings": {
 `"data": {
  "properties": {
    "deptId": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
     "deptName": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "employee": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "empId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "empName": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "salary": {
          "type": "float"
        }
       }}}}}}
```

I have inserted Sample Data as follows

```
PUT company/data/1
{
"deptId":"1",
"deptName":"HR",
 "employee": [
  {
    "empId": "1",
    "empName": "John",
    "salary":"1000"
  },
   {
    "empId": "2",
    "empName": "Will",
    "salary":"2000"
  }
 ]}

PUT company/data/3
{
  "deptId":"3",
  "deptName":"FINANCE",
   "employee": [
      {
        "empId": "1",
        "empName": "John",
        "salary":"1000"
      },
       {
        "empId": "2",
        "empName": "Will",
        "salary":"2000"
      },
       {
        "empId": "3",
        "empName": "Mark",
        "salary":"4000"
      }]
     }
```

How can i Construct a Query DSL for the following

1. Department with the maximum Employees
2. Employee that is present in most departments

I am using Elastic Search 6.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your First Questions answer is in this link [nested inner doc count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) Which Stats

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "employee",
      "inner_hits": {} 
    }
  }
}
```

This Answers your Second Question there is also reading the link attached.

```
GET /my_index/blogpost/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "employee": { 
      "nested": {
        "path": "employee"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_name": {
          "terms": { 
            "field":    "employee.empName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Read Nested Agg](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-aggregation.html)

I hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: Thank you muammad for the solution, just to add to the above, how do i limit the results to in case 1 to department having the maximum employees. and in the second case the employee belonging to the maximum departments.

Comment: As You suggested in edits you can have all that data in bucket object.
Like You pasted and John is in 3 departments in your results.

Comment: in case of first one you will have inner hits against each departmen hich will tell you how many of employes in each department.