# Elastic search nested aggregations - method from documentation is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I'm new to ES and am struggling with nested aggregations.
Here is my dummy data object ([Here is my data object][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7oaM.png). I'm just trying to get the minimum cost out of the "modern" field.

I have read the following posts in regards to the problem I'm trying to solve. None of them have helped me solve the problem
- [Elastic Search 6 Nested Query Aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309243/elastic-search-6-nested-query-aggregations)
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html
- https://madewithlove.be/elasticsearch-aggregations/
- https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2018/10/22/elasticsearch-bucket-aggregations.html
- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9317

Moreover, I've searched all over stackoverflow and have had not had success (**yes**, I've tried just about every solution I've come across with no success).

According to the docs and the above posts and more, a nested aggregation should be ran as follows:

```
GET /loquesea/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "modern_costs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "modern"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_cost": {
          "min": {
            "field": "modern.cost1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, upon completion, this is what I get:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "modern_costs" : {
      "doc_count" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

I've spent hours trying to make just a basic nested aggregation work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved. Turns out that since I didn't declare in the mapping the type of "cars" as "nested", the nested aggregation will not work. Reason being is that in Elastic Search, since the type was not declared as "nested", ES will treat "cars" as an object.